# Navigate Content Pages MVVM xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can someone teach me how to navigate between pages of content? I have been reading many tutorials but I have not been able to achieve it. I have this small code I want to achieve that when pressing the buttons I change between the pages. I use MVVM model there is my MainViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public Page1 PageNumberOne { get; set; }
    public Page2 PageNumberTwo { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.PageNumberOne = new Page1();
    }

}
```

there is my view model of Page1

```
public class Page1
{
    #region constructor
    public Page1()
    {
        GoPage2Command = new Command(async () => await GoPage2());
    }

    private async Task GoPage2()
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Goin to page 2", "ok");
        //code to go PageNumberTwo here
    }
    #endregion

    #region Commands
    public Command GoPage2Command { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

GoPage2Command is binding to a button.
there is my complete project up load to MF [VS proyect](http://www.mediafire.com/?wa7ikuwur6u5s)

Answer (score 0):

Simply call

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new ContentPage());
```

[INavigation.PushAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.pushasync?view=xamarin-forms)

> Asynchronously adds a Page to the top of the navigation stack.

**Example from the page**

```
var newPage = new ContentPage ();
await Navigation.PushAsync (newPage);
Debug.WriteLine ("the new page is now showing");
var poppedPage = await Navigation.PopAsync ();
Debug.WriteLine ("the new page is dismissed");
Debug.WriteLine (Object.ReferenceEquals (newPage, poppedPage)); //prints "true"
```

**Your Exmaple**

```
private async Task GoPage2()
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Goin to page 2", "ok");
    //code to go PageNumberTwo here
    Navigation.PushAsync(new PageNumberTwo());        
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I had tried that before and I get the following error: The type or namespace 'PageNumberTwo' could not be found (are you missing or using  directive or an a assembly reference?)

Comment: @ArmandoAlvarez does PageNumberTwo exist, if so, you will need to add a using directive to its namespace

Comment: I use the directive to its namespace, I am thinking maybe it's an visual studio problem, I am reinstalling right now

Comment: @ArmandoAlvarez Its highly unlikely to be a visual studio problem, though not impossible

Comment: I finish reinstalling VS and give me the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I was using Xamarin Live to do the tests, connecting by cable does not give any error. I do not recommend using Xamarin Live not only gives that problem but many more